# Can you keep track of indices using a map in python or other higher order functions?

Tags: javascript, python, lambda, higher-order-functions

In Javascript, when we perform higher order functions we maintain access to the element, index, and iterable we perform the function on. For example:

```
[10,20,30].map(function(element, index, array) {
  return elem + 2  
}
```

We maintain access to the element, the index, and the array.

In Python is this possible to do with Python's built-in Map, Filter, and Reduce methods? To my knowledge, the callback inside reduce only has access to the current accumulated and the next value. Please let me know how you would maintain access to the index while you are mapping with Python as you would in Javascript. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `map` or `filter` you could just use [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate) that returns `(index, element)` tuples:

```
>>> l = [10,20,30]
>>> [i * x for i, x in enumerate(l)]
[0, 20, 60]
```

Of course you can combine `enumerate` with `map` as well but it would result to more complicated code:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: x[0] * x[1], enumerate(l)))
[0, 20, 60]
```

Comment: Yeah so the answer is that you don't have the ability to do it with the map, filter, or reduce function and should use enumerate instead?

Comment: @JonathanMitchell Yes, there's no parameter etc. in Python `map` to get indices or some other method that would be exactly like Javascript `map`. If you want to have both the item and the index `enumerate` is the way to go. Note also that in Python `map` or `filter` don't only work with lists/arrays but with any iterables. In the above examples `l` could just as easily be generator instead.